# How to mint an spl token in a Rust script?

Tags: spl-token, rust, mint, token-account

I've been learning Rust and piecing together some code that will mint 1 spl-token. My script compiles, creates an account, initializes a mint, creates the associated token account, and mints 1 token to this account. I think the problem is the first account created is not a token account, so even though the mint works, there is no balance increase. Any idea on the correct way to create a token account?

'mint_account' is supposed to be the address of the new token. Here is the mint_account created on Devnet:

https://solscan.io/account/4d6xjX5o5tDSQv6FFexzsMq6wiQQk7cxeVvfZj4m5Xwj?cluster=devnet

The code I've found recommends this format, which I updated for spl_token_2022:

```
let create_account_instruction: Instruction = solana_sdk::system_instruction::create_account(
    &signer_wallet.pubkey(),
    &mint_account.pubkey(),
    minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption,
    Mint::LEN as u64,
    &spl_token_2022::ID,
  );

  let decimals = 0;

  let initialize_mint_instruction: Instruction = spl_token_2022::instruction::initialize_mint(
    &spl_token_2022::ID,
     &mint_account.pubkey(),
     &signer_wallet.pubkey(),
     None,
    decimals,
  )?;

  let recent_blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().await?;

  let transaction: Transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[create_account_instruction, initialize_mint_instruction],
     Some(&signer_wallet.pubkey()),
    &[&mint_account, &signer_wallet],
    recent_blockhash,
  );
```

Comment: Can you add the code that's tripping the error and the error that you're seeing? This code looks perfectly correct

Comment: Hey Jon, the code is correct. I re-ran it using spl-token dependency instead of spl-token-2022 and it checks out. My guess is the explorers aren't yet updated to recognize these as tokens because running the CLI command to check the balance shows it correctly. 

Here is my token minted once I changed to spl-token...

https://solscan.io/token/AqbDacHXobhHZNz6SHaLKcAcDSoAbnoPM93X6mbK7B6C?cluster=devnet

Comment: Ah yes, it'll take some time for the all of the client-side libraries / applications to properly support token-2022. It's all being worked on!